# RegEx: Using /i vs. /g (/g replaces whitespace but /i doesn't)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want an array containing only letters (I'm writing a function to check for pangrams). Using this code with `/g` gives me an array of only letters and no spaces (`lettersArr.length = 34`):

```
var s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
var lettersArr = s.replace(/[^a-z]+/i, "").split("");
console.log(lettersArr);
```

However, using the same code with `/i` gives me an array containing the letters as well the space between quick and brown (`lettersArr.length = 43`). Since `/i` is just case-insensitive, shouldn't they give the same results? Is this just a RegEx or Javascript bug?

Comment: Without the `/g` flag, `.replace()` only matches the first occurrence. Most programming languages apply the `/g` flag by default while *JavaScript unexpectedly does not*. You must explicitly add it.  Also, keep in mind you can use many flags simultaneously; so flagging `/gi` will solve your issue in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[^a-z]+/i` Matches  [space][.] *First Match* which is  **[space]**

When you do

```
   s.replace(/[^a-z]+/i, "")
```

gives `'Thequick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'` ***`length = 43`***

---

`/[^a-z]+/g`  [T][space][.] *Matches Globally*

> Capital **T** is missing here

gives `"hequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"`  ***`length = 34`***

---

So you need to use both flags because you want to match **capital T** too.

`/[^a-z]+/gi` [space][.] *Matches globally case insensitive*

`s.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, "")`

**Gives the desired string**

`"Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"` ***`length = 35`***

Afterwards you can split it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add the `g` flag to the regex, so it's only replacing the first match, in your case the first space character.

If you add the `g` flag, it works:

```
var s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
var lettersArr = s.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, "").split("");
console.log(lettersArr);
```

Using the `g` flag means that `.replace` won't stop at the first match.

Note that without `i` the array should be of length 35, and with `i` 34, so I'm not sure how you're getting 26 or 28.

Comment: You can add both flags as well, to give you global case-insensitive replacement: `s.replace(/[^a-z]+/ig, "")`

Comment: @Sly_cardinal Thanks, that's probably what OP wanted, I have updated the answer

Comment: Yes, I definitely meant lengths 34 and 35. I didn't know you could include both `i` and `g`, thank you guys.